# Running spark Application against remote EC-2 spark cluster from scala eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I am running below spark code on my local Eclipse Scala IDE. I have created EMR spark cluster on AWS. I need to access remote spark to run my application in IDE itself. I have already tried this code by making a jar and run that jar using spark-submit. But now I want to run this spark application in my IDE only.
Basically, my code is to read data from AWS s3.

Below is my code:

```
package com.S3connection
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import com.amazonaws._
import com.amazonaws.auth._
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest
import java.io.File;
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
object sparktest {
  def main(args:Array[String]){

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                 .setMaster("spark://ec2-22-104-209-46.compute-
                             1.amazonaws.com:7077")
                 .setAppName("S3")
                 .set("spark.driver.host", "174.61.47.360")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._
   //val yourAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("AKIAJ6T3YPF5CCFD4D3A", "ayit1dlgbAg2rAdi3zEUm/bQncQuHuNMVcMDD/4D")
 sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "ZK111IABDG3DDNBDG4D3A")
 sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "ayit1dlgjbfjdfgbjbdgknQncQuHvhdbcsv12D/6D")
  val student = sqlContext.read.json("s3://Informatica-files/students.json")

  student.show()
 }
}
```

I have set master as ec-2 master node URL which is also spark master and spark-driver host as my master node IP

after executing code in Eclipse it is showing following error.

```
17/06/11 22:31:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/06/11 22:31:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(gbhog); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(gbhog); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/06/11 22:31:27 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
```

How can I resolve this error and execute my program in Eclipse using remote Ec-2 spark. Also any networking configuration is required to access remote spark on AWS from my IDE?

Comment: I would remove the AWS access and secret access keys ASAP, as well as the ec2 host.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply AM. sorry, sir but I didn't get your solution can you please elaborate this.

Comment: It wasn't a solution, just a suggestion to remove your credentials from the code you posted, so you won't get hacked.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I had similar issue running my code on eclipse in Centos. Eventually the mapping between host and ip in my /etc/hosts was wrong. If this is windows (Windows 7) please check C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and ensure the mapping is correct. Commands hostname and ipconfig(ifconfig in centos) would help.